# how to Fix Unable to find explicit activity class

Tags: android

```
public class MultiColumnActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Button filterButton;
    Context context = this;
    ListView lview;
    // GridView lview;
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Select all", " Date ", " Location to ",
            " Client Name ", " Product code ", "Product Description",
            "Location from", "Quantity", "Pallets" };

    protected ArrayList<CharSequence> selectedInterests = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        // lview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        filterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterbutton);
        filterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        populateList();
        listviewAdapter adapter = new listviewAdapter(this, list);
        lview.setAdapter(adapter);

        int lm = lview.getCount();
        System.out.println(lm);

    }

    private void populateList() {

        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "DATE");
        temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "LOCATION TO");

        temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "CLIENT NAME");
        temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "PRODUCT CODE");
        temp.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "PRODUCT DESCRIPTION");
        temp.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, "LOCATION FROM");
        temp.put(SEVENTH_COLUMN, "QUANTITY");
        temp.put(EIGTH_COLUMN, "PALLETS");

        list.add(temp);

        HashMap<String, String> temp1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp1.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "7 / 2 / 2013");
        temp1.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "SW00-000");
        temp1.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "Mercury Direct");
        temp1.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "MERCUR-A5WW2013-491-000-000-Loose");
        temp1.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "A5 WORLDWIDE HOLS 13 C");
        temp1.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, "Warehouse");
        temp1.put(SEVENTH_COLUMN, " 5000");
        temp1.put(EIGTH_COLUMN, "1");

        list.add(temp1);

        HashMap<String, String> temp2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp2.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "7 / 2 / 2013");
        temp2.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "DAH22A");
        temp2.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "Hurtigruten Ltd");
        temp2.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "HURTI-NORWY13-000-000-000-10");
        temp2.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "NORWAY 2013");
        temp2.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, "ShrinkWrap");
        temp2.put(SEVENTH_COLUMN, " 4000");
        temp2.put(EIGTH_COLUMN, "1");

        list.add(temp2);

        HashMap<String, String> temp3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp3.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "7 / 2 / 2013");
        temp3.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "DAH22A/02");
        temp3.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "Hurtigruten Ltd");
        temp3.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "HURTI-NORWY13-000-000-000-10");
        temp3.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "NORWAY 2013");
        temp3.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, "ShrinkWrap");
        temp3.put(SEVENTH_COLUMN, " 4000");
        temp3.put(EIGTH_COLUMN, "1");

        list.add(temp3);

        HashMap<String, String> temp4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp4.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "7 / 2 / 2013");
        temp4.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "DAH22A/02");
        temp4.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "Hurtigruten Ltd");
        temp4.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "HURTI-NORWY13-000-000-000-10");
        temp4.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "NORWAY 2013");
        temp4.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, "ShrinkWrap");
        temp4.put(SEVENTH_COLUMN, " 4000");
        temp4.put(EIGTH_COLUMN, "1");

        list.add(temp4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.filterbutton: {

            showDialog();
            break;

        }

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    private void showDialog() {

        // arraylist to keep the selected items
        final ArrayList seletedItems = new ArrayList();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Select The Fields");

        /*
         * boolean[] checkedInterests = new boolean[items.length]; int count =
         * items.length;
         * 
         * for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { checkedInterests[i] =
         * selectedInterests .contains(items[i]);
         * 
         * }
         */

        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    // indexSelected contains the index of item (of which
                    // checkbox checked)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            // If the user checked the item, add it to the
                            // selected items
                            // write your code when user checked the checkbox
                            seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                            selectedInterests.add(items[indexSelected]); // by
                                                                            // anup

                        } else if (seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                            // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove
                            // it
                            // write your code when user Uchecked the checkbox
                            seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));

                        }
                        onChangeSelectedSelection();

                    }
                })
                // Set the action buttons
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // Your code when user clicked on OK
                        // You can write the code to save the selected item here

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // Your code when user clicked on Cancel

                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog = builder.create();// AlertDialog dialog; create like this
                                    // outside onClick
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onChangeSelectedSelection() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (CharSequence selection : selectedInterests)
            stringBuilder.append(selection + ",");

        // filterButton.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
        String input = selectedInterests.toString();
        System.out.println(input);
        if (input.contains("Date")) {



             Intent intent = new Intent();

             intent.setClassName("com.nous.demoexample", "com.nous.demoexample.Dateactvity");

             startActivity(intent);



        }

    }

}
```

second class:

```
public class Dateactvity extends  Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.date);


  }

 }
```

manifies file code :

```
<application android:name=".Dateactvity"></application>
```

This Error is coming.

```
09-12 10:58:34.253: E/AndroidRuntime(275): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.nous.demoexample/com.nous.demoexample.Dateactvity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare like...

```
<activity android:name="com.nous.demoexample.Dateactvity"></activity>
```

And use intent like...

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MultiColumnActivity.this,Dateactvity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Still same Error is coming please fixed my issue i have changed ur code but same Error

Comment: in this condition  if (input.contains("Date")) { am calling new intent} how to call plz tell

Comment: Same issue i dont know where am doing mistake  please check again see my code still same Error is coming

Comment: if u want i can send my Source code its not working dear..please check

Comment: @DevRaj you have delcared an activity under application tag in manifest. check my post. use activity tag

Comment: @Hardy in the same Example i want to Print data in List view in same list then how i will implement it i don't want to create another Activity

Comment: I cant get it. Can you explain me more ?

Answer (score 0):

If your activity outside main package then declare like this :

```
<application android:name="com.nous.demoexample.Dateactvity"></application>
```

Instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setClassName("com.nous.demoexample", "com.nous.demoexample.Dateactvity");
```

Write like this :

```
Intent oIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.nous.demoexample.Dateactvity.class);
```

Comment: please check this issue :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757327/how-to-filter-data-date-wise-location-wiase-in-given-example-within-same-list

Answer (score 0):

declare activity in manifest-

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.packageName.MultiColumnActivity
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
          android:name="com.example.packageName.MultiColumnActivity
          android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category        android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>   <activity
          secondActivity detail></activity>
</application>

Comment: within <application></application> mention all activities present in project and make one of them as Main by using <intent-filter>.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an entry of activity like below

```
  <activity
        android:name=".Dateactvity" >

    </activity>
```

Not under application tag

```
  <application android:name=".Dateactvity"></application>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file you have to register your `DateActivity` using `<activity>` tag not with `<application>` tag.

> ```
>  <application
> android:allowBackup="true"
> android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
> android:label="@string/app_name"
> android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
> <activity
>     android:name="com.nous.demoexample.MultiColumnActivity
>     android:label="@string/app_name" >
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>     </intent-filter>
> </activity>
>    <activity
>     android:name="com.nous.demoexample.Dateactvity
>     android:label="@string/app_name"/>
> ```

and start your `Dateactivity` as below:

> ```
>  Intent intent = new Intent(MultiColumnActivity.this,Dateactvity.class);
>     startActivity(intent);
> ```