# How to Filter data Date wise Location wiase in Given Example within same List

Tags: android

```
     package com.nous.demoexample;

        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.EIGTH_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.FIFTH_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.FIRST_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.FOURTH_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.SECOND_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.SEVENTH_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.SIXTH_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.THIRD_COLUMN;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.GridView;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import com.paresh.demoexample.R;

        public class MultiColumnActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
            private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
            Button filterButton;
            Context context = this;
            ListView lview;
            // GridView lview;
            final CharSequence[] items = { "Select all", " Date ", " Locationto",
                    " Client Name ", " Product code ", "Product Description",
                    "Location from", "Quantity", "Pallets" };

            protected ArrayList<CharSequence> selectedInterests = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                init();

            }

            private void init() {
                // lview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
                lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

                filterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filterbutton);
                filterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                populateList();
                listviewAdapter adapter = new listviewAdapter(this, list);
                lview.setAdapter(adapter);

                int lm = lview.getCount();
                System.out.println(lm);

            }

            private void populateList() {

                list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "DATE");
                temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "LOCATION TO");

                temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "CLIENT NAME");
                temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "PRODUCT CODE");
                temp.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "PRODUCT DESCRIPTION");
                temp.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, "LOCATION FROM");
                temp.put(SEVENTH_COLUMN, "QUANTITY");
                temp.put(EIGTH_COLUMN, "PALLETS");

                list.add(temp);

                HashMap<String, String> temp1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp1.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "7 / 2 / 2013");
                temp1.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "SW00-000");
                temp1.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "Mercury Direct");
                temp1.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "MERCUR-A5WW2013-491-000-000-Loose");
                temp1.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "A5 WORLDWIDE HOLS 13 C");
                temp1.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, "Warehouse");
                temp1.put(SEVENTH_COLUMN, " 5000");
                temp1.put(EIGTH_COLUMN, "1");

                list.add(temp1);

                HashMap<String, String> temp2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp2.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "7 / 2 / 2013");
                temp2.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "DAH22A");
                temp2.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "Hurtigruten Ltd");
                temp2.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "HURTI-NORWY13-000-000-000-10");
                temp2.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "NORWAY 2013");
                temp2.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, "ShrinkWrap");
                temp2.put(SEVENTH_COLUMN, " 4000");
                temp2.put(EIGTH_COLUMN, "1");

                list.add(temp2);

                HashMap<String, String> temp3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp3.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "7 / 2 / 2013");
                temp3.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "DAH22A/02");
                temp3.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "Hurtigruten Ltd");
                temp3.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "HURTI-NORWY13-000-000-000-10");
                temp3.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "NORWAY 2013");
                temp3.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, "ShrinkWrap");
                temp3.put(SEVENTH_COLUMN, " 4000");
                temp3.put(EIGTH_COLUMN, "1");

                list.add(temp3);

                HashMap<String, String> temp4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp4.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "7 / 2 / 2013");
                temp4.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "DAH22A/02");
                temp4.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "Hurtigruten Ltd");
                temp4.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "HURTI-NORWY13-000-000-000-10");
                temp4.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, "NORWAY 2013");
                temp4.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, "ShrinkWrap");
                temp4.put(SEVENTH_COLUMN, " 4000");
                temp4.put(EIGTH_COLUMN, "1");

                list.add(temp4);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.filterbutton: {

                    showDialog();
                    break;

                }

                default:
                    break;
                }

            }

            private void showDialog() {

                // arraylist to keep the selected items
                final ArrayList seletedItems = new ArrayList();

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Select The Fields");

                /*
                 * boolean[] checkedInterests = new boolean[items.length]; int count =
                 * items.length;
                 * 
                 * for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { checkedInterests[i] =
                 * selectedInterests .contains(items[i]);
                 * 
                 * }
                 */

                builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
                        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            // indexSelected contains the index of item (of which
                            // checkbox checked)
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                                if (isChecked) {
                                    // If the user checked the item, add it to the
                                    // selected items
                                    // write your code when user checked the checkbox
                                    seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                                    selectedInterests.add(items[indexSelected]); // by
                                                                                    // anup

                                } else if (seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                                    // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove
                                    // it
                                    // write your code when user Uchecked the checkbox
                                    seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));

                                }
                                onChangeSelectedSelection();

                            }
                        })
                        // Set the action buttons
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // Your code when user clicked on OK
                                // You can write the code to save the selected item here

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // Your code when user clicked on Cancel

                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog = builder.create();// AlertDialog dialog; create like this
                                            // outside onClick
                dialog.show();
            }

            protected void onChangeSelectedSelection() {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (CharSequence selection : selectedInterests)
                    stringBuilder.append(selection + ",");

                // filterButton.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                String input = selectedInterests.toString();
                System.out.println(input);
                if (input.contains("Date")) {

                //here i want to display Date Only Listview 
                }


                if(input.contains("Locationto")){
                    // here i want to display location to only in same list 
                }

            }

        }
```

Constant.java

```
package com.nous.demoexample;

public class Constant {
    public static final String FIRST_COLUMN = "First";
    public static final String SECOND_COLUMN = "Second";
    public static final String THIRD_COLUMN = "Third";
    public static final String FOURTH_COLUMN = "Fourth";
    public static final String FIFTH_COLUMN = "Fifth";
    public static final String SIXTH_COLUMN = "Sixth";
    public static final String SEVENTH_COLUMN = "Seventh";
    public static final String EIGTH_COLUMN = "Eighth";

}




 listvieadapter.java
     package com.nous.demoexample;

        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.FIRST_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.FOURTH_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.SECOND_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.THIRD_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.FIFTH_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.SIXTH_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.SEVENTH_COLUMN;
        import static com.nous.demoexample.Constant.EIGTH_COLUMN;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;

        import com.paresh.demoexample.R;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class listviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
            Activity activity;

            public listviewAdapter(Activity activity,
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
                super();
                this.activity = activity;
                this.list = list;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return list.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return list.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            private class ViewHolder {
                TextView txtFirst;
                TextView txtSecond;
                TextView txtThird;
                TextView txtFourth, txtFifth, txtSixth, txtSeventh, txtEigth;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ViewHolder holder;
                LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.FirstText);
                    holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.SecondText);
                    holder.txtThird = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ThirdText);
                    holder.txtFourth = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.FourthText);
                    holder.txtFifth = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.FifthText);
                    holder.txtSixth = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.SixthText);
                    holder.txtSeventh = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.SeventhText);
                    holder.txtEigth = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.EigthText);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
                holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
                holder.txtSe

    cond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
            holder.txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
            holder.txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));
            holder.txtFifth.setText(map.get(FIFTH_COLUMN));
            holder.txtSixth.setText(map.get(SIXTH_COLUMN));
            holder.txtSeventh.setText(map.get(SEVENTH_COLUMN));
            holder.txtEigth.setText(map.get(EIGTH_COLUMN));

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

I am able to display all data date wise location wise and ....together But i want to Filter data -date wise location means if we check in location wise then it should Print location Only if filter date wise it should display date ..in list please help i have tired much But unable to do this....i have create check Box for select option date wise filter ,  location wise filter so please check my code if u want i can send complete code .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EditText to search then you have to write your own filter method..here is an example [Custom ListView Search](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/) .

you have to change `filter` method something like this.

```
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    worldpopulationlist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (WorldPopulation wp : arraylist) {
            if(isDate)
            {
              if (wp.getDate().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
              {
                  worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
              }
            }else{
             if(wp.getLocation().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))  
              {
                worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
              }  
            }

        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: i have not Used EditText Box ..please see my code u can Understand or give ur email id i will send ur source code every thing is don't filter is not able Understnd

Comment: i have used Check Box for filtering please help i am stuck in this issue from last 2 week not able to Understand